# Mocking i.o vertx async handler

Tags: junit, vert.x

How to mock Vertx.io async handler to return  different asyncResult  for different JsonObject as a parameter for mongoClient methods.

I have tried by pass `Mockito.any()` as a parameter in `doAnswer()`

`Mockito.when(asyncResult.result()).thenReturn(result);`

```
 Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<AsyncResult<JsonObject>>() 
 {
    @Override
    public AsyncResult<JsonObject> answer(InvocationOnMock arg0) throws Throwable {

    ((Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>>) arg0.getArgument(3)).handle(asyncResult);
    return null;
    }
  }).when(mongo).findOne(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

I have 2 different results in for 2 different query so for one result I have mocked as above , but for another gives different result for  different `JsonObject`. So how to mock same method with different result in same function.